# Product of ρ and φ

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics

Consider a charge distribution $ρ_1(r)$ and the potential $φ_1(r)$ due to it. Consider another charge distribution $ρ_2(r)$ and $φ_2(r)$ due to it. Both distributions have finite extent, but are otherwise arbitrary and need not have anything to do with each other. Show that the $$∫ρ_1(r) φ_2(r) dv = ∫ρ_2(r) φ_1(r) \; dv$$ where the integrals are taken over all space. Solve this in two different ways as follows.

a) Consider the two collections of charges to be rigid objects that can be moved around. Start with them initially located very far apart, and then bring them together. How much work does this require. Imagine moving collection 1 toward collection 2, and then the other way around.

b) Consider the integral of $∫E_1 E_2 \; dv$ over all space, where $E_1$ and $E_2$ are electric fields due to the two distributions. By using the vector identity $∇ \cdot (E_1φ_2) = (∇ \cdot E_1)φ_2 + E_1 \cdot ∇φ_2$ (and similarly with the $1$'s and $2$'s switched), rewrite the integral $∫E_1 E_2 \; dv$ in two different ways.

This is a homework question, and I have no idea where to start. If someone could show me how to set this equation up to solve, then I would deeply be thankful.

Comment: Use dollar signs for formulas: eg $\int$

Comment: Right click on formula to show latex code eg for rho $\rho$.

Comment: Without showing us what it is you've tried or what it is you don't understand, this question will likely be closed as off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solved in a single line of math:

$$\left\langle\rho_1,\phi_2\right\rangle=\left\langle\rho_1,\nabla^{-2}\rho_2\right\rangle=\left\langle\nabla^{-2}\rho_1,\rho_2\right\rangle=\left\langle\phi_1,\rho_2\right\rangle$$
where the self-adjointness property of $\nabla^{2k}$ has been used, and $\left\langle\right\rangle$ represents the integration inner product.

Alternately, you can also try your approaches "A" and "B", but they'll be far more complicated than the method I gave above.

Method "A" proceeds via a physical pictoral argument; in short, what is the self-assembly energy of the non-overlapping distribution pair? The self-assembly energy ought to be invariant with respect to its manner of construction, and there are two obvious ways to do it. Try it and see what you get.

Method "B" is a direct application of the multivariate product rule; just apply calculus. It'll give the answer you want.